# How to create multi-line abbreviations

Tags: insert-mode, abbreviations, multiple-lines

I want to create an abbreviation for  multiple lines. For example, when I type Doc, it has to print a four line text like

```
###############
# function :
# returns :
#
##############
```

When I tried to do this the first line works, but other lines aren't inserted.

I tired with `abbr`, `iabbr` and `imap`. I'm not able to get the desired behavior. I would prefer not to write a function to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, you can do with the `^M` character in your abbrev, for example:

```
iabbrev Doc #^M# function :^M#^M# returns :^M#
```

will be transformed into:

```
#
# function :
# 
# returns :
#
```

To get `^M` you need to type `<C-v>` `<CR>`.

Comment: Thanks. But still I couldn't get it. I wrote this command line in a plaugin. Is it necessary that I need to write this line directly in .vimrc? It doesn't work

Comment: you can use it directly in your command line to try it out first. What output do you get?

Comment: I tried. Sorry, my multiline text has pipeline after ^M. That is the problem I think. I escaped it. Bow it works :)